# How to set defaultProps for object React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

My problem:
When i set one of three optional values, then that only value is visible, other default values are gone.

```
type ComponentProps = {
 title: string,
 children: JSX.Element,
 options: {
  iconType?: string,
  color?: string,
 }
}
 const Component = ({ title, children, options = {color: '#D3A82B', iconType: 'alert'}: ComponentProps) => {
 return <AnotherComponent color={options.color} iconType={options.iconType}/>
}
```

Usage:

```
<Component iconType='danger' />
// default color option is gone
```

Comment: Your "usage" doesn't match the `ComponentProps` you've provided. Your `COmponentProps` says you're expecting an `options` prop with `color` and `iconType` optional properties, but your usage shows you're expecting `color` and `iconType` to be props themselves, not within `option`....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "usage" doesn't match the `ComponentProps` you've provided. Your `COmponentProps` says you're expecting an `options` prop with `color` and `iconType` optional properties, but your usage shows you're expecting `color` and `iconType` to be props themselves, not within `option`....?

#### If you meant to have `options`

It only makes sense to provide a default value for `options` if `options` is optional in your component props type; otherwise, the default won't be used since the caller is required to supply `options`.

If you want to supply defaults for the `iconType` and `color` properties of `options` and also for options itself, you need to mark `options` optional and then supply defaults for `color` and `iconType` (perhaps via destructuring), and also provide an overall default for `options` (which can be `{}` if all options have their own defaults):

```typescript
type ComponentProps = {
    title: string;
    children: React.ReactNode;
    options?: {
        // Added `?` to make `options` optional
        iconType?: string;
        color?: string;
    };
};
const Component = ({
    title,
    children,
    //       vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv−−− defaults for `color` and `iconType`
    options: { color = "#D3A82B", iconType = "alert" } = {},
}: //                                                    ^^−− default for `options` as a whole
ComponentProps) => {
    // ...use `color` and `iconType` here...
};
```

Live example (with TypeScript types commented out):

```js
/*
type ComponentProps = {
    title: string;
    children: React.ReactNode;
    options?: {
        iconType?: string;
        color?: string;
    };
};
*/
const Component = ({
    title,
    children,
    options: { color = "#D3A82B", iconType = "alert" } = {},
}/*: ComponentProps*/) => {
    return (
        <div>
            color = {color}, iconType = {iconType}
        </div>
    );
};

const Example = () => {

    // No options at all
    const ex1 = <Component title="ex1">ex1</Component>;

    // Just `color`
    const ex2 = <Component title="ex2" options={{color: "blue"}}>ex2</Component>;

    // Just `iconType`
    const ex3 = <Component title="ex3" options={{iconType: "information"}}>ex3</Component>;

    // Both
    const ex4 = <Component title="ex4" options={{color: "blue", iconType: "information"}}>ex4</Component>;

    return (
        <div>
        {ex1}
        {ex2}
        {ex3}
        {ex4}
        </div>
    );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

#### If you didn't mean to have `options`

...then `ComponentProps needs to be flattened a bit, and you just supply the defaults directly:

```
type ComponentProps = {
    title: string;
    children: React.ReactNode;
    // No `options` layer
    iconType?: string;
    color?: string;
};
const Component = ({
    title,
    children,
    color = "#D3A82B",
    iconType = "alert",
}: ComponentProps) => {
    // ...use `color` and `iconType` here...
};
```

Live example (with TypeScript types commented out):

```js
/*
type ComponentProps = {
    title: string;
    children: React.ReactNode;
    iconType?: string;
    color?: string;
};
*/
const Component = ({
    title,
    children,
    color = "#D3A82B",
    iconType = "alert",
}/*: ComponentProps*/) => {
    return (
        <div>
            color = {color}, iconType = {iconType}
        </div>
    );
};

const Example = () => {

    // No `color` or `iconType`
    const ex1 = <Component title="ex1">ex1</Component>;

    // Just `color`
    const ex2 = <Component title="ex2" color="blue">ex2</Component>;

    // Just `iconType`
    const ex3 = <Component title="ex3" iconType="information">ex3</Component>;

    // Both
    const ex4 = <Component title="ex4" color="blue" iconType= "information">ex4</Component>;

    return (
        <div>
        {ex1}
        {ex2}
        {ex3}
        {ex4}
        </div>
    );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created object with default options called **defaultOptions**.
By doing that i can pass props passed by user into component, as well as spread default options.

```
export const TOOLTIP_DEFAULT_OPTIONS: TooltipOptions = { color: '#D3A82B', iconType: 'danger' };
    
type ComponentProps = {
 title: string,
 children: JSX.Element,
 options?: {
  iconType?: string,
  color?: string,
 }
}

const defaultOptions = {
    ...TOOLTIP_DEFAULT_OPTIONS,
    ...options,
  };

 const Component = ({ title, children, options = TOOLTIP_DEFAULT_OPTIONS : ComponentProps) => {
 return <AnotherComponent iconType={options.iconType} {...defaultOptions}/>
}
```

Comment: That won't let you supply `options` with just `color` or `iconType` and not the other, as the type of `ComponentProps` suggests you want to. (Also: Answers with no explanation aren't useful. Say what you did, and why, in order to make an answer useful.)

Comment: I have added explanation into my answer. My solution is working for me.

Comment: The code in the answer doesn't make sense. First off, what's `options`' in the object literal you're assigning to `defaultOptions`? There's no `options` identifier in scope there. Did you mean for that code to be *inside* `Component`? The code also has a syntax error (missing `}`).